# Concatenate string and variable in script-fu (TinyScheme)

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I am trying to write a simple script-fu function.
I want it to take a `filename` as argument and load this file from a folder (whose path will be hardcoded).

**Base code:**

```
(define (myfunction inputfile)
    (let * ( (image (cat (file-png-load 1 inputfile inputfile)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
...
```

Here is what I want to achieve in a ecmascript syntax:

```
"foldername/" + inputfile
```

I have looked on the Scheme doc, but I see no example of variable+string concatenation...

https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_7.html#SEC61

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Gimp can also be scripted in Python. This is much simpler...

Answer (score 6):

Well it seems that it was simpler than I thought

```
(string-append "myfolder/" infile")
```